# In Kentucky, who is responsible for closing a polling location?

Tags: united-states, voting, us-state-laws

For in person voting tomorrow, Kentucky (USA) will have roughly [200 out of the normal ~3,700 polling locations open](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/us-politics/kentucky-cuts-polling-locations-angry-mob-long-lines-georgia-election-day-disaster-confusion-a9577501.html).

Was a single person responsible for this decision, such as the Kentucky secretary of state or governor?

Or is this delegated to each county? (And what person would be responsible in each county?)

Comment: Tried to narrow the scope of the question, if you want to discuss "why" in the comments, I made a chat -> https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109710/q-in-kentucky-who-is-responsible-for-closing-a-polling-location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [full chain](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2020/06/kentucky-slashes-polling-places-voting-rights-mcgrath-booker-lebron-james/) here is

1. Gov. Beshear
2. KY Board of Elections and Secretary of State (they [seem to work in the same tier](https://www.courier-journal.com/story/news/politics/2020/06/22/kentucky-officials-refute-primary-voter-suppression-claims/3235183001/))
3. County Clerks

> After Kentucky Gov. Andy Beshear delayed the primary from mid-May to June 23 in response to the coronavirus pandemic, he issued an executive order requiring the Board of Elections to expand voting by mail, permit early voting, and limit contact among voters and poll workers during in-person voting. About a week later, the Board of Elections directed county clerks across the state to submit plans that included cuts to the number of polling locations in each county. Counties across the state complied; Louisville’s Jefferson County (pop. 767,000) chose a single polling place, a convention and expo hall with spaced-out voting booths, while Fayette County (pop. 319,000) selected the University of Kentucky’s football stadium.

> All in all, according to the Washington Post, Kentucky officials have reduced the number of polling places in the state from 3,700 in a typical election year to fewer than 200 this month.